# SQL query for creating course lists. GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

I have a mysql table "lessons" from which I want to output a course list for each teacher (see picture).

[image: See image]

Up to now I wanted to use GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT for the output, but I failed so far. I have no idea at the moment. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you identify those four rows as "one course"?  How are the last two columns defined?

Comment: Please re-read your question, and correct this: `GRPUP BY`, SO created an `edit` possibility just for doing so....

Comment: @GordonLinoff Weekdays from 1-5 (Monday, Tuesday...), hours from 1-9 (first hour, second hour...). A teacher can only teach one subject at a time. However, students from more than one class can join a course.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, lessons that are at the same time (based on the last two columns) and for the same teacher and have the same name should be combined as a "course".

If this is the case, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select group_concat(ids) as ids,
       group_concat(class_id) as class_ids,
       teacher, name, weekday_hours
from (select l.class_id, l.teacher_id, l.name,
             group_concat(l.weekday, ':', l.hour order by l.weekday, l.hour) as weekday_hours,
             group_concat(l.id order by l.id) as ids
      from lessons l
      group by l.class_id, l.teacher_id, l.name
     ) l
group by teacher, name, weekday_hours;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your query works so far and you have understood the design of the database.

Comment: I have one more question. Instead of the class_id I would like to print the name of the class. The class name is stored in a table "classes". That means I need INNER JOIN. But unfortunately the query is so complex that I can't understand it. Where do I have to insert it?

Comment: @Lukas . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  This seems to answer the question that you asked here.